# How to Access a Column Value in a Select List within a Tabular Form for Each Row in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex, tabular-form

Within a tabular form using the following sample query, i.e.:

```
select  
"EMPNO",  
"EMPNO" EMPNO_DISPLAY,  
"ENAME",  
"HIREDATE",  
"SAL",  
"DEPTNO",  
"MY_LOV"  
from"#OWNER#"."EMP"
```

I would like to access for each row in my tabular form, the `EMPNO` value for that row, within a select list (query based `LOV`) within "MY_LOV" column.

So basically, the column `MY_LOV` within my tabular form, would be a select list (query based `LOV`) where `MY_EMPNO = :EMPNO` (first column in select query above), for each row in the tabular form.

Comment: A deleted answer below [supplied this link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2359498).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make a named LOV in your shared components.
Then go to the column attributes of the MY_LOV column and for **Display As** select **Select List (named LOV)**.
Then in the List of Values region you can specify which LOV you just created.
The value of the select list will be the value of the MY_LOV column in your query, which means this value should also be EMPNO:

```
select  
"EMPNO",  
"EMPNO" EMPNO_DISPLAY,  
"ENAME",  
"HIREDATE",  
"SAL",  
"DEPTNO",  
"EMPNO" "MY_LOV"  
from "#OWNER#"."EMP"
```

Comment: Bart, not sure if I have made myself clear - I basically need to grab the first column of each row and use this value in a select list query in another column, inorder to retrieve other data from another table, based on each EMPNO value within the where clause. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible using the method above, tonsils. The "retrieve other data from another table" would take place in the named LOV. Which value is selected in your select box would be determined by the value of the column, in this case the EMPNO. Do you need any help constructing the LOV?